# How many Red Dwarf books are there?

Tags: red-dwarf, grant-naylor

I know that there are Red Dwarf books out there. Now my question is, how many Red Dwarf books are there?

I personally only know (by seeing it) of 1 Red Dwarf book myself , but there could be more.

Comment: What research have you done so far to find out how many of these books were published?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are [currently four of them](http://www.reddwarf.co.uk/merchandise/index.cfm?category=books):

*Infinity Welcomes Careful Drivers* - co-authored by Rob Grant and Doug Naylor

*Better Than Life* - Co-authored by Rob Grant and Doug Naylor

*Last Human*    - by Doug Naylor

*Backwards* - by Rob Grant

There are also various script compilations and such, but I've not included them, as it feels like you're only asking about the tie-in novels.